# Multiple counts in a SQL statement

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, count

Is it possible to have more than one count in a SQL statement such as:

```
SELECT 
    student_id, 
    (
        COUNT (ATTENDANCE_ID) 
        from attendance 
        where attendance_id IN ('ABSENT')
    ), 
    (
        COUNT (ATTENDANCE_ID) 
        from attendance 
        where attendance_id IN ('PRESENT')
    )
    FROM attendance;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COUNT` counts values that are not `NULL`. You can transform the unneeded values into NULL for example with `DECODE`. Combining the two as below:

```
select
    student_id, 
    count(decode(attendance_id, 'ABSENT', 1, null)) as absent_count,
    count(decode(attendance_id, 'PRESENT', 1, null)) as present_count,
from
  attendance
group by
  student_id
;
```

Or you could put `0` instead of `null` and use `SUM`.